# OpenLayers with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, reference, openlayers

So, under this hyperlink : [EXAMPLE](http://garcia.cba.pl/openlayers/index2.html) i have some example of use OpenLayers and jQuery Mobile. Unfortunately, i have one issue with this example :

```
ReferenceError: OpenLayers is not defined
```

Of course everything works fine when i remove jQuery Mobile library, but when i will use them above error occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your example.

The OpenLayers.js must be referenced first.
Change the script include order from:

```
<script src="resources/js/mobile.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="resources/js/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/mobile.js"></script>
```